# Dealing with .logicdata file

Tags: networking, firmware, internet-security

I am practicing for CTFs and have this assignment on hardware security.

I was given a .logicdata file and wonder how I can open it to analyze it?

Answer (score 1):

#### I was given a `.logicdata` file and wonder how I can open it to analyze?

> After some googling, we found that Salea Logic software can be used to examine logicdata files

Source [FIRST SecLounge CTF 2020 – ICS Challenges - CUJO AI](https://cujo.com/first-seclounge-ctf-2020-ics-challenges/)

It is a log file produced by a [Saleae Logic Analyzer](http://%5BProduct%20Summary%20-%20Saleae%20Support%5D(https://support.saleae.com/user-guide/product-summary)). The required software can be downloaded from [Software Download - Saleae Support](https://support.saleae.com/logic-software).

<sup>Disclaimer: I am not affiliated with Saleae in any way, no do I use any of their products or software.</sup>